# 'Straight' Parentheses around Matrices

Tags: fonts, matrices

I'm using the `txfonts` package in order to access the `\lambdaup` symbol. In order to maintain consistency with other documents, I'm then loading the `lmodern` package to reset the font families. However, I would like to keep the style of parentheses for large (> 2 line) matrices (via the `\pmatrix` environment from `amsmath`) that `\txfonts` gives me. Is there a way to do this?

Compare the following example with/without the `\usepackage{lmodern}` line commented out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts} % \lambdaup
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

First image shows the 'default' style of parentheses, from CM fonts:

[image: 'Default' style parentheses (CM)]

Second image shows the style of parentheses that I am hoping to achieve, from TX fonts:

[image: Desired style of parentheses (TX)]

Third image shows egreg's proposed answer:

[image: egreg's answer]

Comment: Not sure what you mean with ‘straight’ parentheses, but wouldn't the `bmatrix` environment yield what you want?

Comment: Try loading `lmodern` before `txfonts`.

Comment: @Bibi That does keep both `\lambdaup` and the style of parentheses, but it has the unfortunate side effect of changing the font family for the rest of the text... I need the 'main' font to be CM, to keep it consistent with other documents.

Comment: Have you looked into using the `upgreek` package for upright-shaped Greek characters?

Comment: @Mico Unfortunately that gives a different upright `\lambda` than `\txfonts' - I need the style to be consistent with other documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you shouldn't mix the parentheses of TX with those of CM, but here's how you can do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%\usepackage{txfonts} % \lambdaup
\makeatletter
\let\iftx@libertine\iffalse
\let\iftx@minion\iffalse
\let\iftx@coch\iffalse
\makeatother
\DeclareFontEncoding{LMX}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{TXlettersA}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{TXlettersA}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{TXlargesymbols}{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{TXlargesymbols}{bold}{LMX}{ntxexx}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambdaup}{\mathord}{TXlettersA}{21}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{operators}{"28}{TXlargesymbols}{0}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"29}{TXlargesymbols}{1}


\begin{document}

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \lambdaup \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

$(a+b)c$

$\bigl(a+b\bigr)c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer the parentheses in the style of `txfonts`, you can do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%\usepackage{txfonts} % \lambdaup
\DeclareSymbolFont{TXlettersA}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{TXlettersA}{bold}{U}{txmia}{bx}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{TXlargesymbols}{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{TXlargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{txex}{bx}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambdaup}{\mathord}{TXlettersA}{21}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen}{operators}{40}{TXlargesymbols}{0}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{41}{TXlargesymbols}{1}


\begin{document}

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \lambdaup \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

$(a+b)c$

$\bigl(a+b\bigr)c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's certainly an improvement on what I've managed to do so far, although it doesn't quite do what I want. I may have misunderstood the cause-and-effect of what's going on with the different packages - I'll try and upload an image later to clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @JustinT Added straighter parentheses

Comment: @egreg +1 upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading the deprecated `txfonts` pacakge, with provides both text and math Times Roman glyphs, you could load the newer `newtxmath` package, which doesn't modify the text-mode glyphs. Hence, you can keep the Computer Modern text mode font parts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}             % for 'pmatrix' env.
\usepackage[cmbraces]{newtxmath} % provides '\lambdaup'
\begin{document}
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & \lambdaup\\
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```